# Multiple ternery class bindings in Alpinejs

Tags: alpine.js

Whilst looping through some links, I would like to apply classes to a element based on two ternery conditions, eg:

```
<a 
    :class="route.cond1 === true ? 'bg-red-500' : 'bg-green-500'
    :class="route.cond2 === true ? 'text-blue-500' : 'text-purple-500'"
>
    CLICK
</a>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [class object syntax](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/bind#class-object-syntax) to bind multiple classes:

```
<a :class="{'bg-red-500': route.cond1, 'bg-green-500': !route.cond1,
            'text-blue-500': route.cond2, 'text-purple-500': !route.cond2}">
    CLICK
</a>
```